# Python XML check next item

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

Here is a little xml example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <person id="1">
        <name>Smith</name>
        <city>New York</city>
    </person>
    <person id="2">
        <name>Pitt</name>
    </person>
    ...
    ...
</list>
```

Now I need all Persons with a name and city.
I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf8

import xml.dom.minidom as dom

tree = dom.parse("test.xml")

for listItems in tree.firstChild.childNodes:
    for personItems in listItems.childNodes:
        if personItems.nodeName == "name" and personItems.nextSibling == "city":
            print personItems.firstChild.data.strip()
```

But the ouput is empty. Without the "and" condition I become all names. How can I check that the next tag after "name" is "city"?

Comment: have you tried below?

Comment: yes, but the output is blank.

Comment: but ur second node has no city .. what do want to print fro second person

Comment: i need only persons with a city and ignore all nodes without a city.

Comment: check i have changed the answer.:) sure it works

Comment: thx, i try it later. i'm busy now ;)

Answer (score 0):

use element tree check this [element tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()






for person in root.findall('person'):
    name = person.find('name').text
    try:
        city = person.find('city').text
    except:
        continue
    print name, city
```

for id u can get it by `id= person.get('id')`

```
output:Smith New York
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in minidom:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

def getChild(n,v):
    for child in n.childNodes:
        if child.localName==v:
            yield child

xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.xml')
person = getChild(xmldoc, 'list')
for p in person:
    for v in getChild(p,'person'):
        attr = v.getAttributeNode('id')
        if attr:
            print attr.nodeValue.strip()
```

This prints id of person nodes:

```
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml, you can use xpath to get in one step what you need:

```
from lxml import etree

xmlstr = """
<list>
    <person id="1">
        <name>Smith</name>
        <city>New York</city>
    </person>
    <person id="2">
        <name>Pitt</name>
    </person>
</list>
"""

xml = etree.fromstring(xmlstr)

xp = "//person[city]"

for person in xml.xpath(xp):
    print etree.tostring(person)
```

`lxml` is external python package, but is so useful, that to me it is always worth to install.

xpath is searching for any (`//`) element `person` having (declared by content of []) subelement `city`.